# How to color area chart based on y-axis values in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a problem to color my graph based on `y`-axis sequential.

What I want to do is for instance if my graph is on `y`-axis from `0-1000`, I need to color it for

- `< 500` in 'red',
- `500-800` in 'green'
- `> 800` in 'yellow'.

So far I did color the whole chart based on `min y` and `max y` - for example, if my `y = 800` I got in 'green' but I need a part of chart which is `< 500` in red and `> 500` in green.

Data are in array: `var data = [10, 150, 340, 800, 500, 300]`.

I was using this approach:

**define colorScale**

```
           var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain(d3.ticks(0, 800, 2))
                .range(["red", "green"]);
```

**appending to area**

```
       svg.append("path")
                .data([data])
                .attr("class", "area")
                .attr("d", area1)
                .style('fill', function (data) {
                 for (var i=0; i< data.length; i++) {
                    return colorScale(data[i]);
                   }
                });
```

Comment: Use a SVG mask.